# unable to fetch record through join in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I am just fedup to get following error message.

> Error Number: 1146
>       Table 'codeign.lc_64' doesn't exist
>       SELECT * FROM (`lc_question`, `lc_64`, `lc_1`, `lc_district`) JOIN `lc_answers` ON `lc_question`.`id_question` =
>   `lc_answers`.`id_question`
>       Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/CI/test2/system/database/DB_driver.php
>       Line Number: 691

here is following my query.

```
//assume i have this value $dist = 64, $type = 1, $dist_name =Delhi

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('lc_question');
$this->db->join('lc_answers', 'lc_question.id_question = lc_answers.id_question');
$query = $this->db->get_where(array('lc_answers.id_district' => $dist, 'a.question_type' => $type, 'a.question_level' =>$dist_name));
return $query->row_array();
```

Comment: Okay, so did you have a specific question? Or did you just want to let us know you were annoyed? If you're looking to fix the issue, it seems rather obvious from the error message that the table `codeign.lc_64` doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

[`get_where()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::get_where) requires a table name for the first argument. Since you already define the table with `$this->db->from('lc_question');` I suggest you use `where()` instead.

Here I used method chaining and the `get('table_name')` method. No need for `db->select('*')` because `$this->db->get('mytable');`  produces "SELECT * FROM mytable".

```
$query = $this->db
    ->join('lc_answers', 'lc_question.id_question = lc_answers.id_question')
    ->where(array('lc_answers.id_district' => $dist, 'a.question_type' => $type, 'a.question_level' =>$dist_name))
    ->get('lc_question');
return $query->row_array();
```

You might still have problems because I don't see where the alias "a" (as in `'a.question_type'`) is defined.